# Customise Caption numbering in MS word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, numbering

If I have a sequence of Table (caption) numbers in MS word:

```
Table 1
Table 2
Table 3
etc
```

How can I change to the below?

```
Table 2.1
Table 2.2
Table 2.3
etc
```

Note the heading numbering in the document begins with 2, in case this can be referenced.

Comment: Does this help? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/include-chapter-numbers-in-captions-HP005189384.aspx

Comment: @darthbith Unfortunately the link no longer works

Comment: For future reference, I googled "Microsoft word captions per chapter": https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/word-change-caption-numbering-from-sequential-to-chapter-numbering/ If you let me know if this helps, I can provide an answer here

Comment: @darthbith thanks. Unfortunately I can't get this working, I think because I have a separate doc for each chapter and can't get the heading 1 style to start from 3.

Comment: You can right click on the chapter number and select "Set Numbering Value", then you can start from arbitrary numbers. Then the chapter numbering should work.

Comment: @darthbith thanks. Sadly, that doesn't work, it remains fixed at 1.

Comment: I don't know why; it works for me :-)

Comment: @darthbith me neither :-( perhaps it is some kind of override from the sytle menu. Thanks anyway

Comment: What, what remains fixed at 1? The caption? You may need to update your captions... type CTRL+A, then F9

Comment: @darthbith No, the chapter heading ....  see [this new question](http://superuser.com/questions/898833/customise-heading-1-style-starting-number-in-ms-word-2007)

Comment: I answered that question with screenshots... actually, I think I answered this question too :-)

Comment: @darthbith You did answer this question! Post it here and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: OK I'll delete my other answer then, to avoid the double post

Comment: BTW the link for the TeX IDEs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/32374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose a Multi-Level list that includes the heading styles. Then you can right-click on the number to choose the starting value.

[image: multi-level list]
[image: heading-style]

Then right-click on the number and choose:

[image]
[image]

Then you can add Figure and Table captions:
[image]
[image]

And proof that it works:

[image]