# Customise heading 1 style starting number in MS word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I am trying to get MS word to start a chapter number at 3.

I have set the Heading 1 style numbering format to start at 3 - this shows as 3 Heading 1 in the styles list. However, when I use the style for the document title it inserts a 1. I have tried right clicking and using set Number Value but it doesn't work.

My Heading 2 style already works (i.e. 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 is displayed when I use this style).

The reason I am doing this is to try to get word to number my figures as 3.1, 3.2 etc and apparently I need to do this [first](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/word-change-caption-numbering-from-sequential-to-chapter-numbering/). See this [question](https://superuser.com/q/641367/217142)...

My figure captions show as 1.1,1.2,1.3 etc which seems to be related to the chapter number displayed.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

The approach set out [here](https://superuser.com/a/676479/217142) almost works but the caption numbers start from 0, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to work it out:

I had previously set up a List Style which defined the starting number as 1. My headings were linked to this. To solve it I modified the existing list style to start at 3.

This was [described by Shauna Kelly](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html):

[image]

[image]